# How to use lookahead in regex to match a word that only appear in certain context?

Tags: regex

I'm learning regular expression and now I'm on chapter of lookahead. In the class example, if you want to match "sea" only in "seashore", you do:

```
/(?=seashore)sea/
```

or

```
/sea(?=shore)/
```

But what if I want to match "shore" only in "seashore"? I tried:

```
/(?=seashore)shore/
```

and

```
/(?=sea)shore/
```

but none of them work. Did I misunderstand something? As far as I understand, lookahead is like a premise for matching a string. But why I cannot match a "shore" only in context of "seashore"? Anyone can give me a hit? Lots of thanks!

FYI: this is the regex pal I'm using to test my regular expression:http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: You need look-behind in this case.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Oh yeah, I haven't gone through the lookbehind, will check'em out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use lookbehind if it is supported by your regex engine. Like so:

```
/(?<=sea)shore/
```

Otherwise (e.g. in Javascript, where lookbehinds are not supported), you'll have to match the whole thing and use capturing groups to separate the part that you want from the rest.

If you write `/(?=seashore)...` it already expects the `sea...` ahead and so, if it would match, it would match from there. There is no way to just exclude that thing from the match if you use lookahead.